# "awk fatal cannot open file for reading (no such file or directory)" in for loop in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I made a Bash script with an AWK script to read files with network pings and then calculate the parameters that the TCP protocol gets like timeout and estimatedRTT.

I inserted it in a for loop to read all the files in a folder, but it throws the error of unable to read. Here is the code:

```
for f in *.txt
do awk '
function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}

BEGIN {
   alpha=0.125;
   beta=0.25;
}

FNR == 1 {
    sampleRTT=$1;
    estimatedRTT=SampleRTT;
    devRTT=0.0000;
    timeoutInterval=EstimatedRTT;
    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", sampleRTT, estimatedRTT, timeoutInterval)}

FNR > 1{
    sampleRTT=$1
    estimatedRTT=((1-alpha)*estimatedRTT)+(alpha*sampleRTT);
    devRTT=((1-beta)*devRTT)+(beta*(abs(sampleRTT-estimatedRTT)));
    timeoutInterval=estimatedRTT+(4*devRTT);
    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", sampleRTT, estimatedRTT, timeoutInterval)}' %f
done
```

I tried using $f, '$f' and "$f". none works. Just works reading single files at once. I didn't delete the files nor I run the script in another folder.

Comment: Try to enclose `$f` with double-quotes: `"$f"`

Comment: Alredy tried. does not work.

Comment: It must! Try to add `echo "$f";`  before `awk`...

Comment: Why not simply process all files at once?

Comment: `%f` isn't even in the ballpark. The ONLY correct syntax is `"$f"` so change your question to show that and include **the exact error message** that you get when running your script that way as it is utterly impossible for you to get exactly the error message you say you're getting if you use `"$f"` (if the dir was empty it'd be close but then it'd include `*.txt` in the message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to process all `.txt` files with AWK, you can do:

```
awk '...' *.txt
```

and you don't need the `for` loop.

---

Regarding your proposed options for the variable `f`:

- `%f`: clearly **doesn't work**, because `%` is not a Bash operator at all, and you literally pass `%f` as a filename to AWK
- `'$f'`: clearly **doesn't work**, because the single quotes prevent the variable substitution, and you literally pass `$f` as a filename to AWK
- `$f`: **works**, if the filenames contain **no whitespace** characters, **no globbing** characters (such as `*` and `?`), and **no other expandable** characters (such as `~`). In general **avoid by all means** dereferencing a variable without enclosing it in double quotes.
- `"$f"`: **works in any case** and is the **only right way** to dereference (i.e. get the value of) a variable

So, you should use `"$f"` in your `for` loop, and if it still doesn't work, the error must be somewhere else.

---

If the error message is:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `*.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Then you have no `.txt` file in the current directory and Bash uses `*.txt` as the filename passed to AWK.

You can prevent this common problem by enabling glob extension verification:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

In this case, if there are no files matching the glob `*.txt`, then Bash does not pass *any* filename to AWK.

Comment: @EdMorton I was focusing on the options that would make the script work in principle, but I totally agree that variables should *always* be enclosed in double quotes when being dereferenced (except in some rare special cases where the quoting might actually interfere with the intended behaviour). I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in a different scenario. how ever, after added a line to **change directory** to the folder where files are located, the `awk` worked perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash   
cd /folder/where/your/files/are/located
#rest of the code
```

This may not be the answer for question, but hope it save someone's time.

Comment: Yes, very weird, I ran in a similar problem on MacOS, where AWK would work only after cd-in into the files to be worked upon, even though AWK was called with a var containing the path. ‍♂️